# sort based on the second field and then re-order the lines having the same first column but still keep the order on second field for each group

Tags: sort

I want to sort a file.

Input:

```
I1, -2   
I2, -6  
I2, -9  
I1, -8  
I1, -1  
I3, -7  
I2, -4  
I3, -4
```

Output :

```
I2, -9  
I2, -6  
I2, -4  
I1, -8  
I1, -2  
I1, -1  
I3, -7  
I3, -4
```

How to get the following output?

Comment: on what column you want to sort your file? your expected output doesn't seem to be sorted.

Comment: It's unclear how the expected output is sorted. Neither column seems to be in any particular order. Consider updating your question to describe your particular ordering more carefully, and also mention which of the columns you are referring to in the title, and whether the data is delimited by commas or by spaces or by the combination of a single comma and space.

Comment: I1,I2,I3 variables are present in 1st column .  The values for that variable in sorted based on most negative value. The most negative value should be in top. The data is separated by spaces.

Comment: @RaghavaChary Consider editing your question to add clarifications. Don not add clarifications in comments (these may be deleted later).  If there is some _grouping_ of lines that is required, this needs to be explained in the question.  Also, if you talk about "variables", be sure to explain what you mean by that.

Comment: @RaghavaChary The problem is that the first column in your example output is not sorted in I1,I2,I3 - but I2,I1,I3 -> this does not seem to have a reason.

Comment: Please, consider adding this to your question if it corresponds to what you are asking for: "I am trying to 1) group the lines based on the value of column 1; 2) sort _groups_ based on each group's minimum value of column 2 (in ascending order); 3) sort lines _in each group_ based on the values of column 2 (again in ascending order)". (Still not 100% clear, "sort groups" should make more clear that it refers to moving whole blocks of lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty solution would be:

```
<infile sort -t, -rk2,2 \
|awk -F, '{ seen[$1]= (seen[$1]==""? "\0":seen[$1] ORS) $0 }
 END{ for (x in seen) print seen[x] }' \
|sort -z -t, -rk2,2 \
|tr -d '\0'
```

Breaking down:

- `<infile sort -t, -rk2,2` 
  this doing `r`everse sorts the input file *`infile`* on the second field (comma is the separator) as the `k`ey field.
- the *awk* code just reorders the records those having the same first column; we separate each group with *null* character `\0`.
- `sort -z -t, -rk2,2`
  this reverse sorts those blocks (separated with null characters; we are telling that to the sort command with`-z`) on the second field and comma delimited fields. please see the below output just before running this step and add `cat -A` you will see:

  ```
  ^@I1, -8$
  I1, -2$
  I1, -1$
  ^@I2, -9$
  I2, -6$
  I2, -4$
  ^@I3, -7$
  I3, -4$
  ```

  `^@` characters represent the null character, what `sort -z` sees the above input is something like this (I do for human readable and better understanding)

  ```
  ^@I1, -8$      I1, -2$      I1, -1$
  ^@I2, -9$      I2, -6$      I2, -4$
  ^@I3, -7$      I3, -4$
  ```

  you got it, the sort command above sees second fields as following

  ```
   -8$      I1
   -9$      I2
   -7$      I3
  ```

  ... and do reverse sort on these and it changes to following:

  ```
  ^@I2, -9$      I2, -6$      I2, -4$
  ^@I1, -8$      I1, -2$      I1, -1$
  ^@I3, -7$      I3, -4$
  ```

  ... and if we return  back the structure, we have actually this:

  ```
  ^@I2, -9$
  I2, -6$
  I2, -4$
  ^@I1, -8$
  I1, -2$
  I1, -1$
  ^@I3, -7$
  I3, -4$
  ```
- `tr -d '\0'`
  and this removes the added null characters from the result and final output is:

  ```
  I2, -9
  I2, -6
  I2, -4
  I1, -8
  I1, -2
  I1, -1
  I3, -7
  I3, -4
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk`:

```bsh
gawk '
  grp[$1] == "" || $2 < grp[$1] { grp[$1] = $2 }
  { val[$1][$2] }
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
    for (i in grp) {
      PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
      for (j in val[i]) print i,j
    }
  }' ./file
```

The idea is:

- store the minimum value of column 2 for each distinct value of column 1 in the `grp` array
- store each line in the bidimensional `val` array to conveniently retrieve the values of column 2 for each distinct value of column 1 (you may also use `val[$1][$2] = $0` and `print val[i][j]` to preserve the original spacing of the data)
- use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to traverse the `grp` array based on the value of its elements and to traverse the `val[i]` (mono-dimensional) array based on the values of its index (always sorting in ascending order).
  Note that you may need to define your own sorting function if you want to change the sorting order of values of column 1 that share the same minimum value of column 2 (e.g. if you added `I4, -9` to your sample data and wanted `I4` to sort before `I2` in the output).

A portable alternative, based on a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), may be:

```bsh
sort -k2,2n ./file |
  awk '
    grp[$1] == "" { grp[$1] = $2 }
    { print grp[$1] "," $0 }' |
  sort -t, -k 1,1n -k 2,2 -k 3,3n |
  cut -d, -f2-
```

where the "per-group" (i.e. relative to the values of column 1) minimum value of column 2 is prepended to each line, allowing for a subsequent sort based on the per-group minimum value (`-9`, `-8`, `-7`), the value of column 1 (to keep lines grouped by it) and the value of column 2.
`awk` is fed with sorted data to make the script simpler: for each line the per-group minimum value is already known when the line is met, removing the need to store lines in some structure and print them in an `END` block (or to process the file twice).